# Dependency Injection causing both Rspec failure and IRB failure

Tags: ruby, dependency-injection, rspec, mocking, rspec-mocks

Note: I am a Ruby and programming novice.
I have a class called `JourneyLog` I am trying to get a method called `start` to instantiate a new instance of another class, called `Journey`

```
class JourneyLog
  attr_reader :journey_class

   def initialize(journey_class: Journey)
    @journey_class = journey_class
    @journeys = []
  end

  def start(station)
   journey_class.new(entry_station: station)
 end
end
```

When I go into `irb`i get the following issue

```
    2.2.3 :001 > require './lib/journeylog'
     => true
    2.2.3 :002 > journeylog = JourneyLog.new
    NameError: uninitialized constant JourneyLog::Journey
    from /Users/BartJudge/Desktop/Makers_2018/oystercard-challenge/lib/journeylog.rb:4:in `initialize'
    from (irb):2:in `new'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/BartJudge/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/irb:15:in `<main>'
2.2.3 :003 >
```

I also have the following Rspec test

```
require 'journeylog'
describe JourneyLog do
  let(:journey) { double :journey, entry_station: nil, complete?: false, fare: 1}
  let(:station) { double :station }
  let(:journey_class) { double :journey_class, new: journey }

  describe '#start' do
    it 'starts a journey' do
      expect(journey_class).to receive(:new).with(entry_station: station)
      subject.start(station)
    end

  end
end
```

I get the following Rspec failure;

```
1) JourneyLog#start starts a journey
     Failure/Error: expect(journey_class).to receive(:new).with(entry_station: station)

       (Double :journey_class).new({:entry_station=>#<Double :station>})
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ({:entry_station=>#<Double :station>})
           received: 0 times
     # ./spec/jorneylog_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am at a total loss on what the problem is, or where to look for some answers.
I'm assuming I'm not injecting the `Journey` class properly, but thats as far as I can get myself.
Could someone provide some assistance?

Comment: Change `journey_class: Journey` to `journey_class: ::Journey` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: @JayDorsey yep, I still get the same Rspec and irb errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `journeylog.rb` file you need to load the `Journey` class:

```
require 'journey' # I guess the Journey class is defined in lib/journey.rb
```

In the spec file you need to pass `journey_class` to the `JourneyLog` constructor:

```
describe JourneyLog do
  subject { described_class.new(journey_class: journey_class) }
  # ...
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks for your help. I should have remembered the require `journey` line. I'll need to spend more time on my rspec, as the second part of your answer has kind of gone over my head.